# Html.BeginForm with input - Does not Hit Controller Method

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

I have this html with and input submit control at the bottom:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { data_ajax = "false" }))
{
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   @Html.ValidationSummary()

<div style="text-align:center">
    <img alt="baron logo" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/login_logo.jpg")" style="display:inline" ; height:"20%" width="20%" />
</div>
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li data-role="fieldcontain">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { autocomplete = "off" })
    </li>
    <li data-role="fieldcontain">
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <input class="form-control" type="submit" value="Log In" data-theme="b" />
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
}
```

And this controller method in the AccountController class:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          // etc
        }
    }
```

I would expect the Login method to be called when the user clicks on the submit control, however this does not happen. Nothing happens.

How do I get the method to be called?

Comment: So what is happening when you click the submit button ? Your code looks fine. Do you have any javascript events wired up to the submit event to prevent the default form submit behavior ?

Comment: I have a breakpoint set in the controller method, which is never reached. And no, there are no events wired up. Strangely, it did hit the controller method once in debug mode, but not the next time I tried..

Comment: Do you have the `[HttpPost]` and `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attributes applied to that method. And why do you have a `data_ajax = "false"` attribute in the form?

Comment: I am using [AllowAnonymous], [HttpPost] and   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]. data_ajax was there in the code I copied. I removed it, with no change...

Comment: This is weird, but I have to share it: On occasion, this works as expected and if I for example I enter an incorrect user name or password, I will get the expected error message from the controller method (not shown above). But it never works the next time right after this. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

If authentication is required for the site, do you have [AllowAnonymous] attribute for the POST method?

Comment: Yes, I am using  [AllowAnonymous], [HttpPost] and [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]/.